# Trackpad in landscape

Tags: hardware

Did anyone by any chance figure out how to make a hardware bluetooth trackpad work properly in landscape mode?

It seems that the system does not change the axis logic for trackpad coordinates when the android device is put in landscape. As a result, the trackpad cannot reach the far right side of the screen.

We have been struggling with this for a while, now, so any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thx,

Jan